# Connect to SQL Server over Internet

Tags: sql-server, connectivity, remote

I want to connect to SQL Server via Internet:

1. I turned off the firewall
2. I enabled the the DMZ in the router, host address is 192.168.1.24 which is the SQL Server LAN IP
3. I open port in the router for both SQL Server and SQL Server Browser (1433 - 1434)
4. I checked the open port via (canyouseeme) website, and the result is success for 1433 and error for 1434  (I don't know the reason for the error)
5. I made the necessary configuration for the TCP protocols
6. I checked that the server is allowed remote connection

But I failed to connect to the server via Internet.

My LAN IP is 192.168.1.24
The instance is default instance
My public IP is 95.218.156.146 (for example)

When I type (192.168.1.24) in the server name text-box I succeed to connect to the server, 
but I fail to connect when I type 195.218.156.146  or 95.218.156.146 ,1433

Note:

1. When I put the public IP in the brower then the router page appears (meaning  that the public IP is correct)
2. I didn't find *port forwarding* in my router, but I have configured the DMZ and port mapping
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: what is the error? try portqry from you machine with the public IP and see if works. portqry -n 195.218.156.146 -p tcp -e 1433

Comment: "fail to connect" is a useless description of the problem. What is the error message? Are you connecting with windows authentication or SQL authentication? are there any messages in your router logs or SQL Server logs?

Comment: What do you get if you type `telnet 195.218.156.146 1433`? Do you know if your SQL Server is set to dynamic ports? it'll tell you in the SQL Server log

Comment: Exposing Sql Server to the Internet is [not a best practice](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/f/a/8fabacd7-803e-40fc-adf8-355e7d218f4c/sql_server_2012_security_best_practice_whitepaper_apr2012.docx). Why not use a VPN instead?

Comment: Dear jesijesi , Nick.McDermaid and vonPryz 

Thank you very much for your help
for more description , i have attached the pictures , please take a look at it
@jesijesi

Comment: Dear Nick.McDermaid 
Thank you very much for your help
for more description , i have attached the pictures , please take a look at it

@Nick.McDermaid

Comment: I suggest you copy/paste the text from your 1433 connection attempt rather than post as a screenshot (a screenshot is good too). Then it will be searchable. Everything looks like it should be fine. I suggest you go and look in the SQL Server log and see if you can see failed connection attempts in there. It appears that it got through the port OK but SQL Server did not respond before the timeout. You could use the _Advanced_ button in your SSMS connection dialog to extend the timeout to something like 300 seconds (five minutes) to determine whether it's a timeout issue or something else.

Comment: Having said that, the `TELNET` test failed, implying that you can't connect even though your other tests worked OK

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid
yes  the TELNET test failed, also i used the port query tool and the resul was
 " TCP port 1433 (ms-sql-s service): FILTERED "
why its FILTERED ??!! 
i turned off firewall
I do not have an antivirus 
i open "1433" port on my router and checked it via "canyouseeme " wesit and the result was "Success: I can see your service on 95.218.175.225 on port (1433)
Your ISP is not blocking port 1433 "
what else i must do ?? why tenet tset fails ??why port 1433 (ms-sql-s service): FILTERED ?!!

Comment: Of course i get the error when only trying connect over internet
but fo local ip every thing is ok
telnet 192.168.1.24 1433 gets no error

 Starting portqry.exe -n 192.168.1.244 -e 1433 -p TCP  gets

  TCP port 1433 (ms-sql-s service): LISTENING

Comment: i tryed use aonther port rather defult port 1433 , but the same result

Comment: @vonPryz 
I do not know how to use the vpn
is it free ??
can you help me in this by any way

Answer (score 8):

The recommended way to do this is to set up a VPN between the two sites.  The steps to do this vary depending on the particular firewall/router being used.  If a VPN cannot be used, the following information is provided for how to set up a connection with port mapping.  If port-mapping is used, it should only be used in conjunction with additional firewall rules to restrict what source IP addresses can route through the mapped port so that every hacker on earth doesn't have access to your SQL Server.

## 1. Server IP Configuration

Check your Windows Server's IP configuration by running `IPCONFIG / ALL`. Your results can contain both IP addresses, but at least your internal IP:
- `192.168.1.24`
- `95.218.133.168`

## 2. Check your routing

Start a traceroute with the following command: `TRACERT <external IP of server>`. Verify that you receive the route to your server.

> Important do the same from your LAN and from the INTERNET.
>   The results should look like similar to these for the INTERNET check:

```
 1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  <IP of your router>
 2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  <IP of your ISP>
 3    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  <Another IP connecting to your company>
 4     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  outside.yourcompany.com [<public IP of your company>]
 5     3 ms     1 ms     1 ms  dmz.yourcompany.com [<IP of DMZ component>]
 6     3 ms     1 ms     1 ms  router.yourcompany.com [<IP of router>]
 7     3 ms     1 ms     1 ms  sqlserver.yourcompany.com [<IP of server>]
```

> Depending on your firewall settings, you might not get past your company's firewall, but if tracert is going in the right direction, then it "knows" the way. Your firewall is just not telling anybody what your network looks like and might not be forwarding the port request to your SQL Server (See **Router Configuration** later on)

## 3. Check your SQL Server IP Configuration

1. In the SQL Server Configuration Manager open up the branch for **SQL Server-network configuration** and select your instance. (E.g. `Protocols for 'MSSQLSERVER'`)
2. Right click and open up the properties. Verify that you don't have any settings that could inhibit a connection. Close the setting when you have finished.
3. In the right hand pane for the protocol settings verify that the TCP/IP protocol is `'Enabled'`.
4. Now right click the TCP/IP setting and open up the properties. In the Protocol tab...
   a) Verify again that `Enabled` is set to `Yes`.
   b) Verify that the setting `Listen All` is set to `Yes`.
   c) The screen should look like this:
   [image: Protocol Tab]
5. Switch to the IP-Addresses tab and verify for each `IPn` that ...
   a) Active is set to `Yes`
   b) Enabled is set to `Yes`
   c) IP address is your external IP address (or your internal address if you are unable to assign the external address to your SQL Server, because you only have one public IP.)
   d) TCP Dynamic Ports is set to  (No value/empty)
   e) TCP port is set to `1433`
   f) The screen should look a bit like this, but with your IP address:
   [image]
6. An then verify the settings for the `IPAll` portion, by checking that ...
   a) TCP Dynamic Ports is set to  (No value/empty)
   b) TCP Port is set to  (No value/empty)
   c) The screen should look like this:
   [image: IPAll Configuration]

## 4. Check your router configuration

Your public IP is not the server's, it's the router's. If your server is behind the router then you have to ensure your router is forwarding the request to your SQL Server. This configuration setting can vary from router to router. Here a few examples for configuring routers:
 - [Port Forwarding](http://www.zyxel.com/tr/tr/guidemo/zyw70/h_NAT_PortForward.html) (Zyxel)
 - [Setting up static port sharing](https://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7390/knowledge-base/publication/show/893_Setting-up-static-port-sharing/) (Fritz AVM)
 - [How do I configure Port Forwarding on my router?](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/faq/routers/mydlink-routers/dir-605l/how-do-i-configure-port-forwarding-on-my-router) (D-Link)

With the provided tips and tricks you should be able to set your SQL Server to accept connections from the Internet.

> **DISLCAIMER: It is not really recommended to allow connections via the Internet to a database in your LAN. You risk being attacked.**

Comment: thank you very much
TELNET test failed, also i used the port query tool and the resul was
" TCP port 1433 (ms-sql-s service): FILTERED "
why its FILTERED ??!! 
i turned off firewall
I do not have an antivirus 
i open "1433" port on my router and checked it via "canyouseeme " wesit and the result was "Success: I can see your service on 95.218.175.225 on port (1433)
Your ISP is not blocking port 1433 "
what else i must do ?? why tenet test fails ??why port 1433 (ms-sql-s service): FILTERED ?!!

Comment: Of course i get the error when only trying connect over internet
but fo local ip every thing is okay
telnet 192.168.1.24 1433 gets no error

Starting portqry.exe -n 192.168.1.244 -e 1433 -p TCP gets

TCP port 1433 (ms-sql-s service): LISTENING

i tryed use aonther port rather defult port 1433 , but the same result